# ios JTCalendar how to call a method when swiping horizontally to change the page?

Tags: ios, jtcalendar

I am working on a JTCalendar and I want to call some method when user swipes horizontally to change the month. I think overriding a method `viewDidScroll` in `JTHorizontalCalendarView.m` could do that. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

```
- (void)calendarDidLoadNextPage:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar
{
}
```

I call my method inside this delegate method which is called everytime user swipes a month view.

Answer (score 0):

```
  (void)calendar:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar prepareDayView:(JTCalendarDayView *)dayView {
    // This function is called when the calendar view changes   
 }
```

- You can use the above delegate method to perform something when you swipe from one page to next.

Comment: Yes, it will work. But I don't think there is any particular delegate for your requirement. You should proceed with this approach.